Computing the pullback of a connection
Let $\omega_0, \omega_1$ be connections on the principal bundle $P\rightarrow M$. Define a (family of) connection(s) on the bundle $P\times I\rightarrow M\times I, \omega':=(1-t)\rho^*\omega_0+t\rho^*\omega_1$, where $\rho:P\times I\rightarrow P$ is the projection.
How can I show that $i_0^*\omega'=\omega$, where $i_0:p\mapsto (p, 0)$?

Proofread first. Where precisely are you stuck?
